# Serialize compact XML

Tags: c#, xml, xml-serialization

I have a class with four fields (DateTime, Enum, string, string).  I want to serialize it to and from an XML element or a series of XML elements in a compact manner.  For example, I might serialize it to something like this:

```
<i t='234233' a='3'><u>Username1</u><s1>This is a string</s1></i>
<i t='234233' a='4'><u>Username2</u><s1>This is a string</s1></i>
<i t='223411' a='1'><u>Username3</u><s1>This is a string</s1></i>
```

Where 'i' is each class instance, 't' is the DateTime ticks, 'a' is the enum value, and the elements are strings.

I'd prefer to not have a root element, but if I do have it, I'd like it to be as small as possible.

I've tried using XmlSerializer with the XmlWriterSettings class but I can't get rid of the namespaces and root element.

What's the best way of doing this?  I'm not saving to a file, I'm reading and writing to strings in memory.

Comment: XML requires a root element for well-formedness; thus most tools will not produce one.

Comment: For exactly what purpose are you serializing these objects?  That might help us help you.

Comment: What version of .NET are you using? Possibly you could use the DataContractSerializer, which can serialize to a compact binary form of XML.

Comment: Using .NET 2.0.  I'm compacting for transmission over TCP/IP and database storage.  Human readable is preferred to binary, but the shorter the better too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your data is that simple, you can use `XmlWriter` directly:

```
class Data {
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public int Code { get; set; }
    public string First { get; set; }
    public string Last { get; set; }
}

static void Main() {
    var sb = new StringBuilder();
    var xws = new XmlWriterSettings();
    xws.OmitXmlDeclaration = true;
    xws.Indent = false;
    var elements = new[] {
        new Data { Date = DateTime.Now, First = "Hello", Last = "World", Code = 2}
    ,   new Data { Date = DateTime.UtcNow, First = "Quick", Last = "Brown", Code = 4}
    };
    using (var xw = XmlWriter.Create(sb, xws)) {
        xw.WriteStartElement("root");
        foreach (var d in elements) {
            xw.WriteStartElement("i");
            xw.WriteAttributeString("t", ""+d.Date);
            xw.WriteAttributeString("a", "" + d.Code);
            xw.WriteElementString("u", d.First);
            xw.WriteElementString("s1", d.Last);
            xw.WriteEndElement();
        }
        xw.WriteEndElement();
    }
    Console.WriteLine(sb.ToString());
}
```

Running this program produces the following output (I added line breaks for clarity; they are **not** in the output):

```
<root>
<i t="2/9/2012 3:16:56 PM" a="2"><u>Hello</u><s1>World</s1></i>
<i t="2/9/2012 8:16:56 PM" a="4"><u>Quick</u><s1>Brown</s1></i>
</root>
```

You need that root element if you would like to read the information back. The most expedient way would be using [LINQ2XML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb299195.aspx):

```
var xdoc = XDocument.Load(new StringReader(xml));
var back = xdoc.Element("root").Elements("i").Select(
    e => new Data {
        Date = DateTime.Parse(e.Attribute("t").Value)
    ,   Code = int.Parse(e.Attribute("a").Value)
    ,   First = e.Element("u").Value
    ,   Last = e.Element("s1").Value
    }
).ToList();
```

Comment: That does a good job of writing compact strings for me.  I assume XmlReader.Create in a similar fashion to read it back into the class?

Comment: @Moozhe I added an example of how to read it back using LINQ2XML.

Comment: Actually not using Linq since it's .NET 2.0.  I'm working on getting XmlReader to work and error checking for empty or garbage strings.

Answer (score 2):

`System.Xml.Linq`

```
XElement xElem = new XElement("r");
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{
    xElem.Add(
        new XElement("i",
                new XAttribute("t", "234233"),
                new XAttribute("a", "3"),
                new XElement("u", "UserName"),
                new XElement("s1", "This is a string")
        )
    );
}
var str = xElem.ToString();
```

and to read

```
XElement xElem2 = XElement.Load(new StringReader(str));
foreach(var item in xElem2.Descendants("i"))
{
    Console.WriteLine(item.Attribute("t").Value + " " + item.Element("u").Value);
}
```

**PS:**

You don't need to convert `xElem` to string in order to use that xml in memory

Answer (score 0):

I'd just use a `StringBuilder`, personally.

If size is your #1 concern, consider `json` or `yaml` instead of XML.

Comment: My main concern is the best way to read the information back.  StringReader?  XmlReader?  XmlNodeList?  The implementation is the real question.

Comment: You would use `StringBuilder` to form an xml?

Comment: Generally? No. To write something without a root (ie, invalid XML)? Probably.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to implement your own serializer, I believe, which will be a pain.  That, or you could manually strip out what you don't need after serializing, which could work.

If size is your concern, you should be serializing to binary using `BinaryFormatter`.  You can always base-64 encode it if you need to store it as a string.  (`BinaryFormatter` works almost just like `XmlSerializer`, except the output is raw binary, rather than nicely formatted XML.)